# How to load a custom SpriteFont?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

Is there any possible option where you can open a custom SpriteFont? Because I need to add to my game a font that is not in Windows already. I saw this page [Custom Sprite Fonts](http://dudesknight.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/xna-custom-sprite-fonts/) and it's like I want it, but there's no explanation on how to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the page you've linked:

> Now save the bmp, and add it to your xna content (Add >Existing Item >
>   select your bmp file). Then you need to click on the bmp in the
>   Solution Explorer, and in Properties change it under Content Processor
>   from “Texture – XNA Framework” to “Sprite Font Texture – XNA
>   Framework”.

Comment: and than what i need to do ?

Comment: oh, I found a video on YouTube, so i know what to do next now... Just load that bmp file as SpriteFont.                           `font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("BMPFont");` :)